# How to handle multithreading in database in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have problems using the database in nodejs with mongodb.
Specifically when I use findOne in the data loop.
The result is that outp returns an empty value.
Thanks everyone!

```
var room_members = cdb.get().collection('room_members');
var historys = cdb.get().collection('history');
var outp = [];
room_members.find({id_account: ObjectId(deToken._id)}).toArray(function (f_err, f_res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < f_res.length;i++) {
        historys.findOne({
            id_room: ObjectId(f_res[i].id_room)
            }, function (h_err, h_res) {
            if (h_res) {
                outp.push(h_res);
            }
            })
        }
        res.json({
        status: ok,
        message: outp
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're pushing element in `outp` array in the callback of `historys.findOne`, 
and `historys.findOne` doesn't block the thread, ie node won't wait for it to finish to continue execution, the callback isn't called when you call `res.json`.

```
var room_members = cdb.get().collection('room_members');
var historys = cdb.get().collection('history');
var outp = [];
room_members.find({id_account: ObjectId(deToken._id)}).toArray(function (f_err, f_res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < f_res.length;i++) {
        historys.findOne({
            id_room: ObjectId(f_res[i].id_room)
            }, function (h_err, h_res) {
            if (h_res) {
                outp.push(h_res);
            }
            })
        }
        res.json({
        status: ok,
        message: outp
        });
});
```

If you're using this [library](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/), if you don't pass a callback, you get a promise, so you can do like this :

```
var room_members = cdb.get().collection('room_members');
var historys = cdb.get().collection('history');
room_members.find({id_account: ObjectId(deToken._id)}).toArray(function (f_err, f_res) {
    var promises = []
    for (var i = 0; i < f_res.length;i++) {
        promises.push(historys.findOne({
            id_room: ObjectId(f_res[i].id_room)
            }))
        }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(output){
        res.json({
        status: ok,
        message: output
        });
     }).catch(function(err){
        // Handle the error here
      })
 )


});
```

And if you want to use async/await:

```
async function get_room_members_history(req, res) {
      try {
        // Do what you want to get you're deToken using req or whatever you want
        var room_members = cdb.get().collection("room_members");
        var historys = cdb.get().collection("history");
        var rooms_members_array = await room_members
          .find({ id_account: ObjectId(deToken._id) })
          .toArray();
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rooms_members_array.length; i++) {
          promises.push(
            historys.findOne({
              id_room: ObjectId(rooms_members_array[i].id_room)
            })
          );
        }
        var output = await Promise.all(promises);
        res.json({
          status: ok,
          message: output
        });
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error here
      }
    }
```

Comment: Tks. I use the express framework, and use mongodb v4.2.0 and mongodb dependencies ^ 3.3.2.

Comment: So, can you try the solution above ? Does it work ? By the way, this library allow the use of promise, so I strongly recommend you to use it because it so much more easy, especially with async/await.

Comment: I tried it and succeeded! Thank you for that advice, I will treasure it. Thank u very much. :D

Comment: I completed with the async/await feature. It's so much more easy as you can see, it's look like synchronous code

Comment: Yep, really it works very well. I wonder if you have any other way?